# What font is used in this logo (Zapata’s)?

Tags: font-identification

[image]

I have been to [What the Font?](https://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/) and [Identifont](http://www.identifont.com/identify.html), but without success.

Comment: hmm, since the font has been distorted it's going to be tough identifying the right font. Have you tried searching for similar fonts?

Comment: Yes - I have - but ITC benguiat doesn't really match:
https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/itc/benguiat/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a mixture. You have already identified that the A comes from **Benguiat.** The Z and S are **Bookman.** The P and T are different again; I recognise the rounded serifs and can't remember the name of the font. It's a bit like **Souvenir,** so I've included that here too, if only to prove that it's not that.

The tracking and kerning in the example is very tight, and I don't have the tools to replicate that.

[image: ZAS from Bookman and Benguiat]

Comment: OK - thanks - I was beginning to think that as well - but I don't have any source file or info - its been difficult - think Cooper Black - for P T

Comment: Definitely not Cooper Black. The serifs on the T aren't right.